# Load React SPA according to requested route

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-router

I am building a react-router-redux SPA. Currently the application works great. No matter what url the user enters, the server sends index.html and starts in the root route ('/'). What I am trying to achieve is that when a user enters a URL, the server will still send index.html, but react router will know the requested URL and start the SPA from there.

For example, now if I enter the URL mydomain.com/profiles/1, the server will send the file and I will be redirected to the root route. I want that when I enter the same URL, react router will automatically load the component of this route, and not the home component.

This is my routing:

```
<Switch>
      <Route path='/logout' component={Logout} />
      <Route path='/profile/person/:personId' component={PersonProfile} />
      <Route path='/profile/sealant-customer/:customerId' component={SealantCustomerProfile} />
      <Route path="/search/sealant-customers" component={SealantCustomerSearch} />
      <Route path='/data/people' component={People} />
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Redirect to="/" />
</Switch>
```

And it works only via react router links, not via the browser address bar.

It may be an obvious problem, I just couldn't find an answer here in the forums.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if I got your question right, but I used this in my app

```
class App extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
        <Root>
          <Router>
             <Switch>
                <Route path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route path='/profiles/:profileId' component={Profile} />
             </Switch>
          </Router>
        </Root>
    )
}
```

the profileId that is sent via path to Route can be extracted in Profile component as

```
 props.match.params.profileId
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but it isn't what im looking for. Im looking for automatic redirection according to requested URL (from outside of the SPA)

Comment: You want all urls to answer only index.html, which will contain you react app. And then depending on route you want spa to decide which component to show according to url requested. Is that right or not?

Comment: Yea, but im talking about writing the URL in the bar, not pressing a react router link

Comment: This snippet I sent you is not just links in router. It is how react router handles the URL provided to the application. Try using this code and check the react router docs

Comment: The other part of your code is 2 method definitions, and I dont see where they are called.. is that what you're talking about?

Comment: I first made them via functions, then changed and forgot to delete, sorry I confused you. I edited the snippet

Comment: I uploaded my switch code so you can look what I mean.

Comment: Why do you need a redirect line?